# Create XML in SQL (FOR XML EXPLICIT)

Tags: sql-server, xml, cdata, for-xml-path, for-xml-explicit

Need a little bit help to create some XML in SQL Server.

The resulting XML should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root Version="2.17" KFZ="XX-DD 389">
  <Head name="ExecuteAnswer">
    <Key name="AnswerStatus" value="-OK" />
    <Key name="MsgId"><![CDATA[KFHB0907896aAUH223]]></Key>
    <Section name="Command">
      <Key name="Name" value="SetNewCommand" />
      <Key name="Param0"><![CDATA[XX-DD 389]]></Key>
      <Key name="Param1"><![CDATA[]]></Key>
      <Key name="Param2"><![CDATA[0987asfdsafhdsSS]]></Key>
      <Key name="Param3"><![CDATA[0097aSSSHSDOPir0]]></Key>
    </Section>
  </Head>
  <Data></Data>
</Root>
```

I am stuck at adding `<Section>` to the XML, if I add it with `[Section!3!name]` I get this error:

> error -> Key will be overwritten by Section

Code:

```
SELECT 
   1 AS Tag, 
   NULL AS Parent,
   '2.17' AS [Root!1!Version],
   'XX-DD 389' AS [Root!1!KFZ],
   NULL AS [Head!2!name!Element],
   NULL AS [Key!3!name],
   NULL AS [Key!3!value],
   NULL AS [Key!3!CDATA]

UNION ALL               

SELECT 
    2 as Tag,  
    1 as Parent,    
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'ExecuteAnswer',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    3 as Tag,  
    2 as Parent,    
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    'AnswerStatus',
    '-OK',
    NULL

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    3 as Tag,  
    2 as Parent,    
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    'MsgId',
    NULL,           
    'KFHB0907896aAUH223'
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Could anyone help me please?

Greetings Alex

Comment: The two reasons to use the outdated `OPTION EXPLICIT` are `CDATA` sections and some fance namespace issues. Are you aware, that `CDATA` is outdated itself? This is not even supported by SQL-Server anymore and will be omitted implicitly on storing this in native XML... Do you really need these `CDATA` sections?

Comment: Yes the XML that Iam posted is predetermined. So I have to use CDATA Attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment there's no reason for `CDATA` anymore... It is semantically absolutely identical with a properly escaped *normal* `text()` node.

However, sometimes legacy systems or third party tools demand for it.

Something you must know: There is **no chance** to add the `xml declaration` to the XML other than a cast to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and manually append it.

So, if you have to go over string anyway, you might create the XML *clean and easy* with `FOR XML PATH()`, create the `CDATA` as `<xdata>content</xdata>` and do a simple `REPLACE` to change these placeholders to the `CDATA` opening and closing characters.

However: This is an approach with `EXPLICIT`

```
SELECT 
   1 AS Tag, 
   NULL AS Parent,
   '2.17' AS [Root!1!Version],
   'XX-DD 389' AS [Root!1!KFZ],
   NULL AS [Head!2!name!Element],
   NULL AS [Key!3!name],
   NULL AS [Key!3!value],
   NULL AS [Key!3!!CDATA],
   NULL AS [Section!4!name],
   NULL AS [Key!5!name],
   NULL AS [Key!5!value],
   NULL AS [Key!6!name],
   NULL AS [Key!6!!CDATA]

UNION ALL               

SELECT 
    2 as Tag,  
    1 as Parent,    
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'ExecuteAnswer',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    3 as Tag,  
    2 as Parent,    
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    'AnswerStatus',
    '-OK',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    3 as Tag,  
    2 as Parent,    
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    'MsgId',
    NULL,           
    'KFHB0907896aAUH223',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL

    UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    4 as Tag,  
    2 as Parent,    
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    NULL,
    NULL,           
    NULL,
    'Command',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL

    UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    5 as Tag,  
    4 as Parent,    
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    NULL,
    NULL,           
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'Name',
    'SetNewCommand',
    NULL,
    NULL

    UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    6 as Tag,  
    4 as Parent,    
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    NULL,           
    NULL,
    NULL,           
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'Param0',
    'XX-DD 389'
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```